# Output GeckoView web extension console.log to Android logcat

Tags: android, geckoview

Is it possible to have console.log in background and content scripts output into Android logcat?

GeckoView runtime settings contains `javaScriptEnabled`, which works for non extension console outputs. Their [Messaging Example](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/web-extensions.html#messaging-example) also showcases `browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage`, which can be handled via `MessageDelegate`. However, the `console.log` outputs in the scripts don't seem to be affected by either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for: [setConsoleOutputEnabled](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoRuntimeSettings.html#setConsoleOutputEnabled(boolean))
`setConsoleOutputEnabled` will print your console log to both the browser console and logcat. From what I read you should only do this for debugging since it may use quite a bit of resource.